Take release "APK Signature Scheme v3 and v4"? not working flutter?


while apply the Gradle enable v3 and v4 signature scheme like as below
android {
   ...
   signingConfigs {
      config {
          ...
          enableV3Signing = true
          enableV4Signing = true
      }
   }
}

After the changes while run the application get the issue attached screen shot for your reference, once v3 and v4 applied how should check the scheme applied correctly in (apk signer verify - cmd), thanks in advance.

Please don't post screenshots of terminal (thus text)  output. >What is the content of app/build.gradle line 67?

line 67: As mentioned above config that line only issue has attached in the screenshot meanwhile that issue has fixed and finally APK build also successful, Here expects the output has 1st screenshot v3 and v4 scheme return false how should i get true in the commend prompt log.

What is the minimum SDK version of your app?

minSdkVersion 24
targetSdkVersion 33

"APK Signature Scheme v2, which was introduced in Android 7.0." (API 24). Thus you don't need APKv1 signatures (which are known to be insecure anyway). May be this is the reason why your build system doesn't create one.
